# change node author with rules. using an array of users with specific role

Tags: nodes, rules

I am creating nodes with rules and the default author for these nodes is the user 1 (admin).

I have a set of users as 'administrator' roles.
e.g: John, Jack, Sophie

Is it possbible with rules(or custom php code in rules) to change the author from admin to one of the 'administrators' in randomly fashion.

workflow:
create node, author admin --> rule --> change author to John, Jack or Sophie --> save node

Answer (score 0):

Enable [Views Bulk Operations](https://drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations)

- Create a view (Table format is the easiest to manage.)
- Add a relationship Content: Author (not required)
- Add the author field so you can see who is the current author
- Add the field Bulk operations: Content
- Under Selected Bulk operations choose Change the author of the content. 
  Save the view.

Now on the view page you will see a table of all your nodes.

- Check the select box next to the rows you need to update the author of.
- Under Operations at the top of your view, choose change the author of content.
- Hit Execute
- On the next page, choose the user and hit next
- on the next page hit confirm.
- Repeat / [Integrate with rules...](http://nodeone.se/en/using-rules-components-with-vbo)

Comment: Thanks allot.
looks great. BUt it seems the admin user is being changed when using VBO.
I will look into the video for rules integration, hopefully I get it to work automatically.